# I am unable to make a session in my php file in localhost. I am redirected even though i created a session

Tags: php, session, cookies

This is my code for login.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>User Logon</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>User Login </h2>
  <form name="login" method="post" action="login.php">
   Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
   Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
   Remember Me: <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" value="1"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login!">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is login.php

```
<?php
/* These are our valid username and passwords */
$user = 'jonny4';
$pass = 'delafoo';

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) ){

    if (($_POST['username'] == $user) && ($_POST['password'] == $pass)) {    

        if (isset($_POST['rememberme'])) {
            /* Set cookie to last 1 year */
            setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], time()+60*60*24*365);
            setcookie('password', md5($_POST['password']), time()+60*60*24*365);

        } else {
            /* Cookie expires in an hour */
            setcookie('username', $_POST['username'],time()+60*60);
            setcookie('password', md5($_POST['password']),time()+60*60););
        }
        header('Location: index.php');

    } else {
        echo 'Username/Password Invalid';
    }

} else {
    echo 'You must supply a username and password.';
}
?>
```

and this is index.php

```
<?php
/* These are our valid username and passwords */
$user = 'jonny4';
$pass = 'delafoo';

if (isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])) {

    if (($_POST['username'] != $user) || ($_POST['password'] != md5($pass))) {    
        header('Location: login.html');
    } else {
        echo 'Welcome back ' . $_COOKIE['username'];
    }

} else {
    header('Location: login.html');
}
?>
```

Now,index files checks for cookie and if unavailable, redirects to login.html

login.html takes values, passes to login.php which creates cookies.

But no matter how many times i do it, the output is same, i am not able to view index file because there is no cookie.. any help?

Comment: session_start() at the top of the file.

Comment: You're not starting a session anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your index.php file. It has error

```
<?php
/* These are our valid username and passwords */
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'user';

if (isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])) {
//var_dump($_COOKIE['username']); exit;
    if (($_COOKIE['username'] != $user) || ($_COOKIE['password'] != md5($pass))) {    
        header('Location: login.html');
    } else {
        echo 'Welcome back ' . $_COOKIE['username'];
    }

} else {
    header('Location: login.html');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this section:

```
if (($_POST['username'] != $user) || ($_POST['password'] != md5($pass))) {    
    header('Location: login.html');
} else {
    echo 'Welcome back ' . $_COOKIE['username'];
}
```

To:

```
if (($_COOKIE['username'] != $user) || ($_COOKIE['password'] != md5($pass))) {    
    header('Location: login.html');
} else {
    echo 'Welcome back ' . $_COOKIE['username'];
}
```

Note that `$_POST` changed to `$_COOKIE`

Comment: I'm wondering since the post values hasn't been passed anyway, why doesn't it go to the `else` part?

Comment: Because that is if condition. In here "if isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])) {" have vale.(True). So it is going to first If condition. Inside the if condition "if (($_COOKIE['username'] != $user) || ($_COOKIE['password'] != md5($pass))) {   " getting false. So it is going to else part